# Merge or synonymize the "reification" and "reify" tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Both the tags [reification](/questions/tagged/reification) and [reify](/questions/tagged/reify) currently exist on StackOverflow and seem to be for the exact same concept.

As this is not a concept I'm yet familiar with and as both tags have tag wikis I don't want to just step in and retag the questions myself. Here's what the wiki excerpts currently have to say:

- [reification](/questions/tagged/reification) × 16

  > Reification refers to process of taking an abstract concept and making a concrete representation out of it.
- [reify](/questions/tagged/reify) × 7

  > To "reify" means to take an abstract concept and make a concrete representation out of it. For example, in Lisp lambdas allow you to reify the concepts of procedure abstraction and application.

(Neither tag has a full wiki, just an excerpt each.)

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I'm not an expert and looking at the tagged questions the only difference I can see is a very small one:

- Some languages have a `reify` keyword or function (for example, [Clojure](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reify), [Template Haskell](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2011/2011-12-27-template-haskell.md)) which could be used to achieve a "reification"and so [reify](/questions/tagged/reify) might be for something not as conceptual.
- The reification process can be present in other languages that have no special construct  and that use a reification in their compilation/intepretation process (like .Net generics or Java reified types)

Not sure this difference justifies two different tags.